# Restarting functions yields unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

I'm creating a simple tic-tac-toe game and I have a button that when clicked resets all of the variables affected by the clickHandler function and clears the elements from the table cells, virtually restarting the game. However, when a new game is started before the end of the game is reached, the game starts saying that X and O have been to the same cells and skipping turns. What is wrong with this code, why is it behaving like this?
Here is the fiddle if you want to test the results firsthand. http://jsfiddle.net/YdRLg/

```
//Creates the variables needed to be manipulated later
var X = 'X';
var O = 'O';
var currentPlayer;
var turnCount = 0;
var xMoves = [];
var oMoves = [];
var cellTracker;
var winAlert;
var winConditions = [
    ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'],
    ['c4', 'c5', 'c6'],
    ['c7', 'c8', 'c9'],
    ['c1', 'c4', 'c7'],
    ['c2', 'c5', 'c8'],
    ['c3', 'c6', 'c9'],
    ['c1', 'c5', 'c9'],
    ['c3', 'c5', 'c7']
];
var button = $('button');

/*Set's the current player to X if turnCount is odd
And to O if turnCount is even*/
var setCurrentPlayer = function () {
    if (turnCount % 2 === 0) {
        currentPlayer = O;
    } else {
        currentPlayer = X;
    }
};

//Pushes cellTracker's value to the curent player's move variable
var storeMoves = function () {
    if (currentPlayer === X) {
        xMoves.push(cellTracker);
    } else if (currentPlayer === O) {
        oMoves.push(cellTracker);
    }
};

//Compares players moves with the winConditions to determine a winner
var determineWin = function (pMoves) {
    for (var i = 0; i < winConditions.length; i++) {
        if (winConditions[i].length > pMoves.length) {
            continue;
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < winConditions[i].length; j++) {
            winAlert = false;
            for (var k = 0; k < pMoves.length; k++) {
                if (pMoves[k] === winConditions[i][j]) {
                    winAlert = true;
                    break;
                }

            }
            if (!winAlert) break;
        }
        if (winAlert) {
            alert(currentPlayer + " wins!");
            break;
        }
    }
};

//Determines if the game is over
var determineEnd = function () {
    if (turnCount === 9 && winAlert === false) {
        alert("Tie game!");
    }
    if (winAlert === true) {
        $('td').off('click.mygame', clickHandler);
    }
};

//Calls the above functions to simulate the game
var clickHandler = function () {
    turnCount += 1;
    setCurrentPlayer();
    $(this).text(currentPlayer);
    cellTracker = $(this).attr('id');
    storeMoves();
    determineWin(currentPlayer == 'X' ? xMoves : oMoves);
    determineEnd();
    console.log(turnCount, xMoves, oMoves, winAlert);
};

//Calls the clickHandler function when a cell is clicked
$('td').one('click.mygame', clickHandler);

//Starts a new game when the New Game button is clicked
$('button').bind('click', function () {
    $('td').empty();
    turnCount = 0;
    xMoves = [];
    oMoves = [];
    winAlert = false;
    $('td').one('click.mygame', clickHandler);
});
```

Comment: A better idea, instead of having different variables, would be to store all your options in an object and have another object with the defaults and when you want to reset just extend from the default object.

Comment: What do you mean by store all my options?

Comment: I mean this: `var defaults = {X:'X', O:'O', turn:0, xMoves:[], ...}`

Comment: @elclanrs What would this do?

Comment: It would clean up your code a bit. I'm just suggesting a better data structure.

Comment: @elclanrs I'll play around with it thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are not removing all the event handlers when restarting the game

```
$('button').bind('click', function () {
    $('td').empty();
    turnCount = 0;
    xMoves = [];
    oMoves = [];
    winAlert = false;
    $('td').off('click.mygame')
    $('td').one('click.mygame', clickHandler);
});
```

ie: when you start the game you register `clickHandler` for all tds, then you click few of them causing them to be removed but others are still present in the event registry. Then you restart the game by adding one more set of event handlers to all tds which means now some tds have two `clickHandler`s registered. You can test it by adding a `console.log('clicked')` in the `clickHandler` method

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RGXXa/)

Comment: @user2449973 it looks like you are working on this for last 3 days... all the best

Comment: I have been, it's my first personal project and I'm learning a lot from it, mostly thanks to the community here.